# option is still visible in select after remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile

Hi all I have two select fields, on select field first if user select option value one or two then in select field of second all options are visible but if it select option two in first then option two want to remove from select id second. Following is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var index3,str;
</script>

<select id="first"  onchange="chk();">
<option value = "one">one</option>    
<option value = "two">two</option>    
<option value = "three">three</option>    
</select>

<select id="second">
<option value = "one">one</option>    
<option value = "two">two</option>    
<option value = "three">three</option>     
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
function chk()
{
    index3 = document.getElementById("first");
    str= index3.options[index3.selectedIndex].value;

    alert("str:"+str);

    if (str=="two")
    {
          $("#second option[value='two']").remove();
    }

    else
    {
          if ( $("#second  option[value='two']").length == 0 )
         {

             $("#second").append('<option value="two">two</option>');
         }
    }
}
</script>
```

In fiddle it works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NWbXt/55/), But on mobile problem is:  If I select option two from select id second, and then select option value two in first select id, then also option two is visible in second select id, if I click on second select id then only it removes.  But in jsFiddle it works perfect. Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done complete bin for above issue. please go through demo link.

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7p

**HTML**

```
<select id="first">
  <option value = "one">
    one
  </option>

  <option value = "two">
    two
  </option>

  <option value = "three">
    three
  </option>

</select>

<select id="second">
  <option value = "one">
    one
  </option>

  <option value = "two">
    two
  </option>

  <option value = "three">
    three
  </option>

</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    $("#first").change(function() {
        var optVal = $(this).val().trim();

        if (optVal == "two") {

            $("#second").find("option[value=" + optVal + "]").remove();
        } else {
            if ($("#second").find("option[value=two]").length <= 0) {

                $("<option value=\"two\">two</option>").insertAfter($("#second").find("option[value='one']"));

            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7p

Comment: thanks for response, but when I try your code on mobile simulator then also same issue means on both select id two option is visible as in second image of orignal question.

Answer (score 0):

check this [Edit](http://jsfiddle.net/NWbXt/57/)

```
$('#first').change(function() {
      $("#second option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a bit odd overall.  If your intention is to remove the item from 'second' if it is selected in 'first', try this update: http://jsfiddle.net/NWbXt/58/

```
$(function() {
    var first = $('#first'),
        second = $('#second'),
        removed;

    first.change(function() {
        var selected = first.val();
        second.append(removed);  //.. add back old option
        removed = second.find('option[value="' + first.val() + '"]').remove();        
    }).trigger('change');
});​
```

Comment: I dont want to remove the item from 'second' if it is selected in 'first'.  I want to remove option value two from 'second' if option value two is selected in 'first'. If option value one and three selected in 'first' then all three options(one,two,three) must be visible in 'second'